# Can I add Google Play Services to already published app?

Tags: java, android, google-play, google-play-services

My game is published and live on Google Play. But in the next update I want to add Play Services. Is this possible, because I read that I have to publish the Play Services first and then the game. If it's possible can you give me detailed instructions, because I tried once and screwed the things.

Comment: Yes you can still add it.

Comment: was my answer helpful?

Comment: I have to wait 7 days for Google to remove my old play services, so when its done I will follow your answer, Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to go back to your source code, add the Google Play Services and build another APK. After that re-upload it to Google Play again, say version 2. The instruction to add Google Play Services to your project is stated in the [Add Google Play Services to Your Project](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup):

To make the Google Play services APIs available to your app:

> Open the build.gradle file inside your application module directory.
>   Note: Android Studio projects contain a top-level build.gradle file
>   and a build.gradle file for each module. Be sure to edit the file for
>   your application module. See Building Your Project with Gradle for
>   more information about Gradle. Add a new build rule under dependencies
>   for the latest version of play-services. For example: apply plugin:
>   'com.android.application'
>       ...
>
> ```
> dependencies {
>     compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
> }
> ```
>
> Be sure you update this version number each time Google Play services
>   is updated.  Check the docs for more info.

Comment: Should I create the play services in the developer console first and then update the app, or it doesn't matter? (I read somewhere that it's important to create the services first)

Comment: following the provided answer is all you need. When you said console, you might be referring to enabling APIs and not Google Play Services.